# Old TV mini-series with a living brain in a lab

Tags: story-identification

Some years ago I saw part of an episode of a sci-fi miniseries (maybe British) with a brain in some research laboratory.  It was the brain of a man who died many years ago.

The time is in the future (I think), and the scientists managed to resurrect the brain with some kind of electrical futuristic equipment, some wires and sensors. We see strange flashbacks of the past mixed with unfocused images of the scientist.

The brain is kept inside a liquid and gradually with time he understands what happened, that he was brought to life, and connected to a some kind of equipment that allows him to see, watch, and think. The scientists explain everything to him and I remember that in the end he gets some kind of body but I'm not sure.

Does anybody remember the name of this nineties TV series or made-for-TV movie?

Comment: Didn't see anything relevant under Live Action TV, but you might find it worthwhile to check http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BrainInAJar in case it wasn't a mini-series...

Comment: To intentionally mis-read the title question... *They're Pinky and The Brain// Pinky and The Brain// One is a genius// the other's insane ..."*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you identify this movie from 80s/90s about memory accessing?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/79279/can-you-identify-this-movie-from-80s-90s-about-memory-accessing)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Could it have been [Cold Lazarus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cold_Lazarus)? The time is right (it was shown in 1996), but some of the details might be different (I think it was a head, not a brain). However, it was a TV mini series (shown in the UK on (unusually) both BBC1 and Channel 4).

Comment: Yes you are right!!! It is indeed a head, not a brain... I'm sorry but it was a very long time ago and I didn't remember this... Many thanks Wikis, I am very happy :)

Comment: @Paulo: lucky guess... :) Glad to help.

Comment: @Paulo This series is actually available on 4 on demand spotted it over the weekend.

Answer (score 4):

Could it have been ["The Brain of Morbius"](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Brain_of_Morbius) serial from Doctor Who?

Comment: No, it's not "The Brain of Morbius"... I'm almost sure the mini series I'm looking for was made in the nineties (1990-99)... Many thanks anyway...