# 1980s TV show where a man wakes from cryogenic suspension and discovers he is just a head?

Tags: story-identification, tv

I'm trying to identify a science fiction TV show I saw in the early-to-mid 1980s or late 1970s. This story was a self-contained episode, so it was probably part of a *Twilight Zone*-like anthology series.

In the story, a man wakes up from cryogenic suspension in a future hospital. He is generally rude and makes unwanted passes at the nurses. He is anxious to leave the hospital, but the doctors tell him he must stay for more medical tests.

A nurse wheels his gurney into an elevator to take him to a lab upstairs. In the elevator's reflective ceiling, he (and the viewer) learn that *he is just a head!* He screams, realizing that his head had been frozen without his body.

The closing shot shows his head on a lab shelf with other heads. He is shouting for help as the other heads try to introduce themselves to the new guy.

Comment: Cold Lazarus? If so, this is a [duplicate](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7225/old-tv-mini-series-with-a-living-brain-in-a-lab/7230#7230). (On reflection, some of the details are different...)

Comment: It wasn't Cold Lazarus. This show was broadcast much earlier and the main character was a head, not a brain.

Comment: Ok, thx. (Just FYI, Cold Lazarus was also a head, the questioner did not remember it correctly.)

Comment: I remember this movie and most of the title, The Second Life of Doctor ( )? I just can't remember the doctors name in the title. PLEASE DISREGARD THIS IS NOT THAT MOVIE!

Comment: Arrgh. I've seen this to, but my memory gets me nowhere

Comment: Not much help, but I've skimmed through episode lists of both Monsters and Tales from the Darkside, and it doesn't seem to be any of these.

Comment: Reminds me a bit of Zelazny's short story "Go Starless in the Night".

Comment: I saw this.  The end was awesome.  But I can't recall.  Maybe "Tales from the Darkside"

Comment: There **is** a 1980's era Twilight Zone episode where something like this happens.

Answer (score 11):

*[Welcome Back Mr. Fox](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0365916/)* (1986) TV short

I too vividly remember this. The reflection on the elevator showing the head with the life support machine was memoable and creepy. A stunning plot twist! I had been looking for this for years and finally found it!!!

Comment: Do you remember any details that might assist in finding this book?

Comment: Awesome!  I come back here periodically checking to see if anyone has figured this one question out!  Thank you!

Comment: I am the Writer-Director of "Welcome Back Mr. Fox". Any Fans who want to text me about their impressions of or questions about WBMF I would be happy to connect with you @ walterpitt@hotmail.com. Walt

Answer (score -2):

This sounds a lot like The TV show "Tales from the Crypt" to me. It ran began in 1989 and lasted for a little under ten years.... I think. Anyway, my guess would be the Tales from the Crypt.

Comment: I can't find anything on the web to suggest that...what's your evidence?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not "Tales from the Crypt".  And, even if it was... which episode?

Comment: As you say, a 'guess'.  You need to provide some type of evidence to support it.