# A sci-fi series episode about ex military man's brain wired to the computer

Tags: story-identification

Trying to remember this stuff I seen years ago.

It was a color short (<1 hour) movie - an episode of some series?, dealing with a retired soldier's conscience being connected to virtual reality, where he is required to remember something important, that will save the lives of his relatives (?) in the real world.

He meets his relatives, talks to them, but suddenly starts to "see" the real world computer that keeps his life at the very end.

I think it was more a "brain in the jar" scenario, rather than mind upload; it's not on the new Outer Limits; the computer was imaged as (at least) post-1980's machine (not some steam science). It's neither Doctor Who, nor Lazarus (remarking to [Old TV mini-series with a living brain in a lab](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7225/old-tv-mini-series-with-a-living-brain-in-a-lab)); neither it is old Outer Limits 's [Brain of Colonel Barham](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Brain_of_Colonel_Barham)

Comment: This seems very much like the recent Source Code movie

Comment: @UserEleventyOne, I've seen that one. Should've marked some of my neurons as 'bad block' and accept an answer, but have a strong feeling of earlier similar experience, so - no, not that, yet.

Comment: When do you recall seeing this, and do you remember it having a production style that seemed current to the time?

Comment: @Solemnity, 2007-2009, style was more like 98..2002.

Comment: I recall a TV show wherein a brain with eyes attached is in a large glass jar of clear liquid, able to see and think. At the end the wife of the brain in the jar is seen with another man, and the liquid in the jar begins to boil.

Answer (score 7):

You may be remembering an episode of [Harsh Realm](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0182587/), which aired between 1999 and 2000.

I never watched it, but some of the details fit the synopsis (though somewhat fuzzily) I can find on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harsh_Realm).

- Thomas Hobbes (the main character) is a retired soldier who is given one last mission: a virtual reality simulation
- His mission is to stop a nuclear detonation from occurring. The synopsis is unclear, but they mention that being successful in the simulation would also save the real world.
- He meets up with other soldiers and people he knows within the simulation.
- Hobbes and the others are trying to find a way out of the simulation

Looking at [the list of episodes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Harsh_Realm_episodes), I'm thinking that you saw the pilot episode.

Comment: I immediately thought of Harsh Realm as well.

Answer (score 4):

This sounds similar to **Project X** (1968), reviewed here: [DVD Savant](http://www.dvdtalk.com/dvdsavant/s3896proj.html).  A military pilot back from a mission crashes, and takes his emergency amnesia pill, but the government hooks him up to what we'd call virtual reality, forcing him to live a false life in the hopes that he'll remember his mission data (about a *hostile-asian-country* super-weapon).

I've never seen it, but recently read that review, so I was primed when I saw your question.  I also thought of **Source Code** when I read the review.

Comment: The description certainly sounds like a good fit, but @kagali-san mentioned the style looking like it was from 98-2002. Looking at the screencaps in that review, I don't get that sort of vibe at all.

Comment: @phantom42, from the description, it sounds close to what I can remember, but a) it's very unlikely for local TV broadcaster to show something like that b) if I've downloaded that somewhere, it must be still there, but (_don't try this at home_) no torrents, edonkey or legit sources are found..

Comment: @user11570, not sure, must try to watch it first.. but thank you for that link, there must be some treasure in all those reviews (not like _Robocop_ or _36 hours_, though)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it’s "[Black Box](https://theouterlimits.fandom.com/wiki/Black_Box)", an episode of The Outer Limits television series.
It was first broadcast on December 11, 1998, during the fourth season.

*A dying soldier's last hours are spent in a techno-dream, where he can finally meet his estranged daughter.*

*With: Ron Perlman, Maria del Mar, Michael David Sims and Peter deLuise*

I watched it recently and the story fits really well.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).