# Can you identify this movie from 80s/90s about memory accessing?

Tags: movie, story-identification

Can you help me recalling the title of a sci-fi movie I saw first in 2000:

About the plot:

- A group of young people can access a (recorded) memory of a man (the man is possibly dead)
- They must dig through the memories of him, but I forgot the purpose of it.
- The memories are about the childhood of the man
- The room in which they access the mans memories is blueish and only the head of the man is visible on a kind of screen

It looks like the Short Movie '[The final moments of Karl Brant](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jFotiDbj-D4)', but I miss the childhood memories in this movie and the group of young people investigating.
As far as I know, the movie is not part of any series

I would very much like to see the movie again.

Comment: Is this definitely a movie? The description reminds me of the 4-part TV series _Cold Lazarus_.

Comment: Reminds me a bit of Johnny Mnemonic....

Comment: It is Cold Lazarus indeed! Thank you very much! :) Finally found this miniseries now. I don't recall it being a series, but it apparently is.

Comment: @Bram - I'll add Cold Lazarus as a formal answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like Dennis Potter's last work, *Cold Lazarus*

[wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cold_Lazarus), [imdb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0115140/)

In the 24th century, a team of scientists extract memories from the cryogenically stored head of a 20th century writer for broadcast on TV.

This 4 part drama followed on from [Karaoke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karaoke_(TV_series))

The blue image of the head: 
[image: http://static.bips.channel4.com/bse/orig/cold-lazarus/cold-lazarus-20090519121149_625x352.jpg]

Depending on what part of the world you live in, you may be able to watch via Channel 4 On Demand [4OD](http://www.channel4.com/programmes/cold-lazarus/on-demand/19947-001)